# Facebook OAuth Dialog ignores scope

Tags: facebook, oauth, dialog, scope, user-permissions

Can anyone think of a reason why the OAuth Dialog would ignore the scope that's requested? I get a dialog that only asks for "basic info" whereas the scope requested is "email,user_birthday,publish_actions"... This same scope works fine on all other apps using the same underlying code. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think people would need more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are getting Facebook OAuth token. This may happen if you cached the previously retrieved token, changed the scope afterwards and so the OAuth authorization process was not restarted to obtain a new token for the new scope. In that case you need to clear the cached token.

If you show some code, we may advise with more specific guidance.